# How to get Android Log messages during runtime of app?

Tags: android, android-logcat, android-log

Is it possible to get a handle of all the Log.d (tag, "") logs from within the application during runtime? I'm creating a test application and I'd like to display a window with a list of all the logs. Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242596/e-printstacktrace-in-string . you can probably use this way. Answer by Idolon

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](https://github.com/androidnerds/logger) awesome stuff.
It works for me