# How to get an error into string same as printed in console in java

Tags: java

My requirement is, I have an application that saves the errors into the database to see later time from the dashboard in my own way. therefore, I want to get the happening errors into string same as the error shows the console. I can the message or other stuff from the error object. but it's not I want. I want to preview the error as the java console shows.

Comment: What sort of "error object". Please edit your question to show an example of an error as shown on your Java console.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242596/e-printstacktrace-in-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get by using `StringWriter` and `PrintWriter` like this.

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(sw);
yourException.printStackTrace(printWriter);
String errorLogAsString = sw.toString();
```